# Hubspot how to know from which template a page is created from?

Tags: hubspot

My [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=hubspot%20how%20to%20know%20from%20which%20template%20a%20page%20is%20created%20from%20) came up little helpful so I bring it up here. Let's say we have a page `About us` where we can edit its module, and its content - though we don't know which template it is created from.

p.s. We can see what pages are created from a given template via [this Hubspot guide](http://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-do-i-figure-out-which-template-a-page-is-using) and what I want here is the reversed direction `what template creates my given page` - it's very tiring going thru all templates to see if our page name is there you know...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer when learning [how to use CTA buttons in Hubspot](http://knowledge.hubspot.com/cta-user-guide-v2/how-to-add-a-call-to-action-cta-to-a-webpage#4-how-to-add-a-cta-to-a-web-page-if-you-don-t-have-a-rich-text-module).

The steps

1. Open the page
2. Edit it
3. Switch to `Setting` tab
4. Go to `Edit template` button
5. (optional) `Open in Design Manager`

[image]